# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener in Adobe CQ5

Tags: spring-mvc, aem, osgi-bundle

I am facing a hard time getting a Spring project to run on Adobe CQ5, here is my StackTrace

> *ERROR* [Timer-3] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/springws] Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3712)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4216)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
>           at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer.startCatalinaContext(TomcatWarDeployer.java:144)
>           at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer.startDeployment(TomcatWarDeployer.java:133)
>           at org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.support.AbstractWarDeployer.deploy(AbstractWarDeployer.java:93)
>           at org.springframework.osgi.web.extender.internal.activator.WarLoaderListener$DeploymentManager$DeployTask.doRun(WarLoaderListener.java:257)
>           at org.springframework.osgi.web.extender.internal.activator.WarLoaderListener$DeploymentManager$BaseTask.run(WarLoaderListener.java:215)
>           at org.springframework.scheduling.timer.DelegatingTimerTask.run(DelegatingTimerTask.java:70)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

web.xml file is

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/osgi-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>                                                                       
        <param-value>org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value> 
    </init-param>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

POM File is

```
 <properties>
    <springdm.version>1.2.0</springdm.version>
    <spring.version>2.5.6</spring.version>
    <equinox.version>3.5.1.R35x_v20090827</equinox.version>
        <felix.bundle.plugin.version>2.0.1</felix.bundle.plugin.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- need to fork otherwise some tests contexts are shared -->
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${felix.bundle.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation -->
                <instructions>

                    <!-- <Private-Package>com.manning.sdmia.web</Private-Package> -->
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.springframework.stereotype;version="2.5.6",
                        org.springframework.ui;version="2.5.6",
                        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation;version="2.5.6",
                        org.springframework.web.servlet.view;version="2.5.6",
                        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation;version="2.5.6",
                        org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support"

                    </Import-Package>
                    <Include-Resource>src/main/resources,src/main/webapp</Include-Resource>
                    <Web-ContextPath>springws</Web-ContextPath>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-osgi-annotation</artifactId>
        <version>${springdm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>       

        <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
<version>2.0.8</version>
```

uploaded the following bundles in Adobe CQ5

```
322  Spring AOPorg.springframework.aop  3.0.6.RELEASE       Active  
332  Spring ASMorg.springframework.asm  3.0.6.RELEASE       Active  
316  Spring Beansorg.springframework.beans  3.0.6.RELEASE       Active  
317  Spring Contextorg.springframework.context  3.0.6.RELEASE       Active  
312  Spring Coreorg.springframework.core    3.0.6.RELEASE       Active  
333  Spring Expression Languageorg.springframework.expression   3.0.6.RELEASE         Active    
339  Spring Web Servletorg.springframework.web.servlet  2.5.6.SEC01     Active  
321  spring-osgi-annotationorg.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations  1.2.1       Active  
315  spring-osgi-coreorg.springframework.osgi.core  1.2.1       Active  
311  spring-osgi-extenderorg.springframework.osgi.extender  1.2.1       Active  
318  spring-osgi-ioorg.springframework.osgi.io  1.2.1       Active  
336  spring-osgi-weborg.springframework.osgi.web    1.2.1       Active  
337  spring-osgi-web-extenderorg.springframework.osgi.web.extender  1.2.1       Active  
249  svnkit bundlecom.day.commons.osgi.wrapper.svnkit   1.3.0.0002      Active
```

Shall i need to upload any other bundles ?
Do let me know, if you need complete project code also. Tried with different options but facing the same issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of CQ/AEM are you using, and where are you placing the web.xml. So I am assuming that you are using the CQ 5.4.

You have uploaded the Spring bundles in the OSGi container, and the web.xml is for the WebContainer, which are not bridged by default, which means that the web container will not be able to identify any bundles on your OSGi container.

You may have to consider Spring DM / Eclipse Gemini (Blueprints) to achieve your purpose. Please refer to the [Spring DM Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/osgi/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/) or [Eclipse Gemini Blueprints Documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/2.0.0.M02/html/index.html) to get started on integrating Spring and OSGi.

You may also refer to this [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/gemini-blueprint-%E2%80%93-converting) if you are in between Spring DM and Eclipse Gemini.